# Stylesheet not appearing in Drupal 7 sub theme

Tags: drupal-7, stylesheet

I added these lines to the read

```
css[979px-1088px.css][name] = 979px - 1088px
css[979px-1088px.css][description] = Stylesheet for smaller screen larger than tablet
css[979px-1088px.css][options][weight] = 11
```

I also added the file 979px-1088px.css to my css folder in the same theme.

I then flushed the cache but when I view source the file isnt appearing.

I was able to get it working by using

```
stylesheets[all][] = 'css/979px-1088px.css'
```

But this appears before the rest of the stylesheets and I would prefer control over the order of the css files.